# How to format quoations in JSON to execute link

Tags: javascript, html, json, groovy

I have a  json configuration file like:

```
   "type": "script",
        "label": "coreapps.archivesRoom.printSelected",
        "script": "emr.fragmentActionLink(${project.parent.artifactId},\"downloadPatientHistory\", \"download\", {{patient.patientId}})",
        "icon": "icon-download",
        "order": -25,
        "require": "!visit && !patient.person.dead",
        "requiredPrivilege": "Task: coreapps.createVisit"  
    }
```

I want 'script' to link to `href="javascript:emr.fragmentActionLink(lfhcforms," downloadpatienthistory",="" "download",="" 7)`

But my HTML view doesn't recongize the correct link. Note that in the below screenshot the link is incomplete.
Any hints?

[image]

Comment: try using single quotes or double escaping the quotes `\\\"`

Comment: single quotes worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your href is a javascript function. I would use single quotes so that it looks like this

`href="javascript:emr.fragmentActionLink(lfhcforms,' downloadpatienthistory',='' 'download',='' 7)"`

Since your data source is that JSON file, you should parse/serialize your JSON object, and alter the `type.script` property, changing those double quotes to single. Parse it, searching for `\"` and replace with `'`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use combination of ' and " to represent a string.

Any of the following will work fine for you

```
href='javascript:emr.fragmentActionLink(lfhcforms," downloadpatienthistory",="" "download",="" 7)'

href="javascript:emr.fragmentActionLink(lfhcforms,' downloadpatienthistory',='' 'download',='' 7)"
```

Just figure out which one is easire for you to make in your case.